# Updating Value in SQL Server using MS Access Using VB.Net Programming

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a critical requirement , need to update a table in Sql server  from access through forms and buttons,
When a user clicks the button in the form he should be able to update the record which is already existing in the database.

For Eg: table has columns -EmployeeID , Employee Name, Employee Location

```
EmployeeID Values
-----
1001|
2301|
3212|
```

Suppose a user wants to update value of EmployeeName alone not employee location ,he should be able to do that in some case employee.

```
update table set EmployeeName=@New_employee_name , Employee Location=@New_employee_location where EmployeeID=@Employee_ID
```

This should be driven through vb. net program inorder to update the user input value in the database.

Comment: You want to update the SQL database with VB.Net code, how does MS Access come into the picture?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a Stored Procedure on the SQL Server, here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateEmployeeByID
(
@ID int, 
@TitleID int, 
@FirstName nvarchar(255), 
@LastName nvarchar(255)
)
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;


UPDATE Employee SET 
TitleID = @TitleID, 
FirstName = @FirstName, 
LastName = @LastName
WHERE  ID = @ID
END
```

Using stored procedures rather than ad-hoc SQL protects you from SQL Injection attacks plus there are performance benefits.

Then using VB.Net you will want to call the Stored Procedure, passing in the updated employee values.

```
Public Sub UpdateEmployeeByID(Byval ID As Int32, Byval TitleID As Int32, Byval FirstName As string, Byval LastName As string)

Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString")
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
conn.Open()
Dim sqlCommand As new SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp_UpdateEmployeeByID", conn)
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TitleID", TitleID)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName)

Try
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As SqlException
'Handle SQL exceptions

Catch ex As Exception
'Handle exceptions

Finally
'clean up resources that access Data
    If IsNothing(sqlCommand) = False Then
        sqlCommand.Dispose()
        sqlCommand = Nothing
    End If
conn.Close()
End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: MsAccess is front end application in my case and using forms and buttons, I meant forms and buttons need to talk to Sql Server using VB.net inorder to update the sql server table.